# How can I reset the reading speed data on a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, kindle-touch, time-to-read

I'd like to test the theory that the Kindle Touch/Paperwhite ignores long pauses between page reads when learning your reading speed for a particular book.  But experimenting is complicated by having to import fresh books for testing.

Is there any way to reset the reading speed data?

Comment: Hey can you report back on your findings?

Comment: @randomusr: I didn't really get anywhere with this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

According to a [Kindle forum thread](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle/ref=cm_cd_pg_pg1?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdPage=1&cdThread=TxPPS6DELQ2IBY) the command to reset this data is:

```
;ReadingTimeReset
```

On a touchscreen Kindle, tap the top of the screen to bring up the search box.  After you type the command and get no results, return to the book.  The status line will show `Learning reading speed...`  Since the search string is saved, you won't have to laboriously type the command again in order to reset again.  That ought to make testing a lot easier.