# Turn of reading speed personalization on Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I know that I can reset personalized reading speed like this:
[How can I reset the reading speed data on a Kindle?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-can-i-reset-the-reading-speed-data-on-a-kindle)

But can I disable reading speed personalization? I want to be able to see how much is left of a chapter, either

- based on some average reading speed or
- number of remaining page turns

But I don't want to see personalized reading speed. The reason it that even though I have reset my personalized reading speed several times, after a while it always says 1 min remaining. I am not sure about the reason for this but I believe that it is because a flip through pages occasionally, for example to re-read a note I made a few pages earlier.